# The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

ConsumerNM is a NM/bridge table/entity.

Its a 1:N relation to Events table.

When I do an insert I get the question title exception.

What do I have to change to make it work?

DO I have to create 2 foreign keys each one pointing to the other ConsumerNM_Key?

```
 public class ConsumerNM
 {
        public ConsumerNM()
        {
           Events = new HashSet<Event>();
        }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int FK_LEADMETA { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int FK_LEADCONSUMER { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }      
}

 public class Event
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }       

        public virtual ConsumerNM Consumer { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Consumer")]
        public int FK_Consumer { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: The PK of `ConsumerNM` is composed by two values `FK_LEADMETA` and `FK_LEADCONSUMER`. The Event class has an FK of `ConsumerNM`, but it has only one property. `Event` must have `FK_LEADMETA` and `FK_LEADCONSUMER`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ConsumerNM` or `Event` are incorrect. You have two options:

First Option:

```
 public class ConsumerNM
 {
        //This is not a PK
        //[Key]
        //[Column(Order = 0)]
        //[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int FK_LEADMETA { get; set; }

        [Key]
        public int FK_LEADCONSUMER { get; set; }  
}
```

`Event` remains unchanged.

Second Option:

```
public class Event
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }       

    public virtual ConsumerNM Consumer { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Consumer")]
    public int FK_LEADCONSUMER { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Consumer")]
    public int FK_LEADMETA { get; set; }

}
```

`ConsumerNM` remains unchanged.

Comment: I would choose 2nd option. I solved it now via fluent api. So the ForeignKey and its string name "Consumer" must be the same as the property name of the navigation property in the same class Event?

Comment: Yes, the string inside the `[ForeingKey()]` attribute must be the same as the name of the navigation property. If the FK is composed by more than one value, you have to put `[ForeingKey]` above all of them

Comment: I thought I have to do in Event.cs: ForeignKey("ParentTable.Key1,ParentTable.Key2") comma separated.

Comment: If you put the `[ForeignKey]` attr in the navigation property, so you have to do `ForeignKey("FK_LEADCONSUMER ,FK_LEADCONSUMER")]`. If you put the `[ForeignKey]` attr in the FKs, you have to repeat it for every value of the FK (passing the name of the navigation property as a parameter), as described in the second option of my answer